# Is there a real alternative now to using GSM for data sending?

Tags: temperature-sensor, web-server, remote-control

I would like to create an Arduino system that sends the temperature in a place outdoors to a server.

I've read in Internet forums that there might be alternatives to GSM and GPRS technology for sending data remotely, but I'm not sure about them. In absence of WiFi, is GSM the best technology today, even that you have to use the SIM plan to use it?

Comment: what's the range? can you use LORA?

Comment: the range could be km-s and I don't live in Germany.

Comment: i don't know what germany has to do with anything, but lora can go several KMs, easily

Comment: ok, sorry, I was totally wrong. I thought that it only was valid in Germany. I'm trying to send some temperature data to a remote server. I'm seeing some tutorials in Arduino that do that, so I'm going to consider it. Do you see any problem in using LoRa for my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GSM (or more realistically now, LTE) is really the only option.

Simply put: you need some method of accessing the internet, and unless you create your own local infrastructure that means using the mobile phone system. It's the only system that is virtually everywhere and doesn't require you to install your own communication system.

So that means some modem device that can communicate with the mobile phone system. GSM is what it used to be, although some mobile companies are now deprecating the GSM system and only really providing UMTS (3G) and LTE (what will eventually be 4G), but LTE modems are quite expensive still.

So yes, you need a SIM to do it. You can't access a mobile phone network without one.

One option that could be a cheaper possibility would be to get a cheap second hand smartphone off eBay (or dig out your old one from the bottom of the desk drawer) and use that as your own mobile WiFi hotspot. Your Arduino device connects to the phone with WiFi, and the phone connects to the UMTS or LTE network using a cheap PayG SIM.

---

LoRA is a technology that is gradually becoming more popular and allows long range wireless communications at low power and low cost. There are areas where LoRA is becoming available, such as [in Munich](https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/community/munich/). Should LoRA become available in your area, or should you invest in your own infrastructure, that could become a viable alternative to using the mobile phone network.

Comment: Sigfox and NB-IOT are also two more technologies.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt So write an answer detailing them. Personally I have never heard of them.